# Why some of the field are being lost when launching ir.actions.act.window from python code in odoo 9?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9

Here is my code. The field default_SampleType's value is shown for 2 seconds or so and then get lost.Question is why the value is not being preserved?

The declaration the field as follows

```
fields.Many2one(string='SampleType',
                    comodel_name='olims.sample_type',
                    required=True

),
fields.Many2one(string='SampleType1',
                    comodel_name='olims.sample_type',
                    required=False

),
fields.Many2one(string='SampleType2',
                    comodel_name='olims.sample_type',
                    required=False

),
fields.Many2one(string='SampleType3',
                    comodel_name='olims.sample_type',
                    required=False

),
```

When I replace sampleType with SampleType1 in context, then this value is shown and it does not get lost. I dont know what is the problem with SampleType field.

```
result = {
                    'name': 'Analysis Request',
                    'view_type': 'form',
                    'res_model': 'olims.analysis_request',
                    'view_id': sample_record,
                    'context': {'default_SampleType': sample_type.id , 'default_Client': client.id, 'default_Sample_id': sample_id,
                                'default_SamplingDate': sampling_date,
                                'default_ClientReference': client_reference, 'default_ClientSampleID': client_sample_ID,
                                'default_SamplePoint': sample_point.id,'default_StorageLocation': storage_location.id,
                                'default_SamplingDeviation': sampling_deviation.id, 'default_SampleCondition': sample_condition.id,
                                'default_LotID': lot_id},
                    'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
                    'view_mode': 'form',
                }
        return result
```

Comment: Your code seems to be OK, so can you post the declaration of the field `SampleType` and also the declaration of the variables which are in the result dictionary, please (I mean `sample_record`, `sample_type`, etc)?

Comment: @forvas Please have a look at declaration in the code description above.

Comment: I'd look directly for an `onchange` method which is bound to be modifying your field.

Look in your Python code for `SampleType` string. I think there must be an `onchange` method being executed which is modifying its value just after the form view is opened.

Comment: @forvas Thanks. It was due to onchange function.

Comment: you're welcome. I posted the comment as an answer so that you can vote it as correct and set the question as closed.

Comment: Oh for sure, thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd look directly for an `onchange` method which is bound to be modifying your field. Look in your Python code for `SampleType` string. I think there must be an `onchange` method being executed which is modifying its value just after the form view is opened.